# search for partial or complete text in array

Tags: php, foreach

I have an HTML search form:

```
 <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="term" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

I then have a foreach loop to check if the array item contains the search term:

```
   <?php if (is_array($data['page'])): ?>
   <?php foreach ($data['page'] as $item): ?>
   <?php foreach($item as $item_member): ?> 
   <?php if(strpos($item_member, $_POST['term']) !== FALSE):  ?>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach ($columns as $key => $column): ?>
    <?php $key = parse_class($key); ?>
    <td class="<?php echo $key['class']; ?>"><a class="cell-link"
    href="<?php echo $details_link . $item[$details_id_field]; ?>">
    <?php  echo (!empty($item[$key['column']])) ? $item[$key['column']] : '&nbsp;'; ?>
    </a></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Here is a more readable version

```
if(is_array($data['page'])){
    foreach($data['page'] as $item){
        if(array_search($_POST['term'], $item)){
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach($columns as $key => $column){
                $key = parse_class($key);
                echo '<td class="' . $key['class'] . '"><a class="cell-link" href="' . $details_link . $item[$details_id_field] . '">';
                echo (!empty($item[$key['column']])) ? $item[$key['column']] : '&nbsp;';
                echo '</a></td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, the search only works if the search term is exactly the same as the name in the item.

The array item contains the following information:

```
234|test|21|Jul 28, 2013|0%|1375026328|1375026328|Test)/
```

I'm really only interested in matching the second value in item (in the example above "test" with the search term "term"

I have tried in_array, strpos with no luck.

For the example above, at the moment a result is only brought up if I enter the exact text "test" in the search form. If I enter "tes" for example which is an incomplete search phrase, nothing shows.

Comment: your code is VERY hard to read with all those `<?php` open tags

Comment: `preg_grep()` will probably do what you want - search an array by regex for strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly `$item` holds the array you referred to.

Add another `foreach` to iterate the elements of `$item` and for every one of the items preform a `strpos($item_member, $_POST['term'])` check instead of `array_search`:

```
 <?php foreach($item as $item_member)): ?> 
 <?php    if(strpos($item_member, $_POST['term']) !== FALSE):  ?>
 <?php  // here do what you gotta do ?>
 <?php    endif;  ?>
 <?php  endforeach;  ?>
```

BUT, if you already know that you're looking to match only the second element - you can skip this `foreach` and simply do:

```
<?php    if(strpos($item[1], $_POST['term']) !== FALSE):  ?>
```

This check will return `true` (or actually the beginning index of the match that was found) for any valid sub-string of test - so if you want only sub-string that start at index `0` you can change the test instead of:
 `!== FALSE`

to

`=== 0`

By the way - the `:` syntax is hard to read - I would change it.

Comment: Hi Alfasin, thanks so much for this, it's starting to work now! The only trouble is now, that for some reason, if I type in an incomplete search term, its bringing up multiple of the same entry

e.g If I type in 't' it brings up 3 results of "test"
If i type in 'te' it brings up 2 results of "test"
if i type in "tes" it brings up 2 results of "test"
If i type in "test" it brings up 1 result of "test" (correct)

Comment: @scott in order to figure it out we need to see the new version of the code

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't know what you intend `234|test|21|Jul 28, 2013|0%|1375026328|1375026328|Test)/` to mean. Is that a string at the 0 index of the array? Are the pipes just a way to visually separate the array elements?

Also, your code is also very hard to read, so I didn't read it. That said, I think I understand what you're trying to do. Let's say you have an array with some stuff in it:

```
$arr = array(
    234,
    'test',
    'Jul 28, 2013',
    'testers',
);
```

And let's say you have a user input string:

```
$input = 'tes';
```

We want to determine if any of the elements in the array contain this string:

```
$matches = array();

foreach($arr as $element) {
    if (strpos("$element", $input) !== false) {
        #match found, store it
        $matches[] = $element;
    }
}

var_dump($matches);    //contains two elements, 'test', and 'testers'
```

Output of that `var_dump`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "test"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "testers"
}
```

You should be able to adapt this to your specific use case. By the way, the quotes around `$element` in that `strpos` call are to cast it to a string. I doubt this is necessary in PHP (can't recall), but just in case ...

Comment: Hi sgroves, the first bit: 234|test|21|Jul 28, 2013|0%|1375026328|1375026328|Test)/ (is what's contained in the array $item) with | to seperate. I'm going to try your method now. Thank you